# TFLite Custom Model detection with ESP32CAM

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I've some problem with my tensorflow model, it was a model to detect a stawberry. It work perfect with my webcam which is has 1280 x 720 (16:9) resolution, but there is some problem when i'm trying to do it with espcam with 800 x 600 (4:3) resolution. It wont draw the bounding box correctly like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEHg6.png)
I'm using the pre-trained model from tf2 detection model zoo, SSD MobileNet 320x320.

Here is the code:

```
# Import packages
import os
import argparse
import cv2
import cvlib as cv
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
import importlib.util

# private ip kamera
url = 'http://192.168.1.38/cam-hi.jpg'


# Define and parse input arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in',
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',
                    default='detect.tflite')
parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',
                    default='labelmap.txt')
parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',
                    default=0.5)
parser.add_argument('--resolution',
                    help='Desired webcam resolution in WxH. If the webcam does not support the resolution entered, errors may occur.',
                    default='8000x600')
parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',
                    action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir
GRAPH_NAME = args.graph
LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels
min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)
resW, resH = args.resolution.split('x')
imW, imH = int(resW), int(resH)
use_TPU = args.edgetpu

# Import TensorFlow libraries
# If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow
# If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library
pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')
if pkg:
    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:
        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
else:
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:
        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate

# If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model
if use_TPU:
    # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'
    if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):
        GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'

    # Get path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, MODEL_NAME, GRAPH_NAME)

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, MODEL_NAME, LABELMAP_NAME)

# Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from
# https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview
# First label is '???', which has to be removed.
if labels[0] == '???':
    del (labels[0])

# Load the Tensorflow Lite model.
# If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument
if use_TPU:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,
                              experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
    print(PATH_TO_CKPT)
else:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get model details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)

input_mean = 127.5
input_std = 127.5

# Check output layer name to determine if this model was created with TF2 or TF1,
# because outputs are ordered differently for TF2 and TF1 models
outname = output_details[0]['name']

if ('StatefulPartitionedCall' in outname):  # This is a TF2 model
    boxes_idx, classes_idx, scores_idx = 1, 3, 0
else:  # This is a TF1 model
    boxes_idx, classes_idx, scores_idx = 0, 1, 2

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()

# Initialize video stream
# videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(imW,imH),framerate=30).start()
time.sleep(1)

# for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
while True:
    img_resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgnp = np.array(bytearray(img_resp.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    im = cv2.imdecode(imgnp, -1)
    #im = cv2.rotate(im, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
    # Start timer (for calculating frame rate)
    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))
    input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)

    # Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)
    if floating_model:
        input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()

    # Retrieve detection results
    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[boxes_idx]['index'])[
        0]  # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
    classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[classes_idx]['index'])[0]  # Class index of detected objects
    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[scores_idx]['index'])[0]  # Confidence of detected objects

    # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        # parse if score >70%
        if ((scores[i] > 0.8) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):
            # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
            # Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
            ymin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][0] * imH)))
            xmin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][1] * imW)))
            ymax = int(min(imH, (boxes[i][2] * imH)))
            xmax = int(min(imW, (boxes[i][3] * imW)))

            cv2.rectangle(im, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)

            # Draw label
            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])]  # Look up object name from "labels" array using class index
            label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i] * 100))  # Example: 'person: 72%'
            labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2)  # Get font size
            label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10)  # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
            #cv2.rectangle(im, (xmin, label_ymin - labelSize[1] - 10), (xmin + labelSize[0], label_ymin + baseLine - 10),(255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)  # Draw white box to put label text in
            cv2.putText(im, label, (xmin, label_ymin - 7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0),2)  # Draw label text

    # Draw framerate in corner of frame
    cv2.putText(im, 'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(frame_rate_calc), (30, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', im)

    # Calculate framerate
    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2 - t1) / freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1 / time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone please explain why and how to fix it. Thank You